# ADF Popup Not Appearing

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to figure out ADF but having an issue.
I'm trying to create a simple dialog popup, but it refuses to appear. I've tied it to a command button to try to force it to appear, but without luck.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" version="1.2"
version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<f:view>
    <af:document title="Manager">
        <af:popup id="popupDialog">
            <af:dialog title="Manager" id="dialog1" type="yesNoCancel">
                <af:panelGroupLayout layout="horizontal">
                    <af:outputText value="This is a test" />
                </af:panelGroupLayout>
            </af:dialog>
        </af:popup>
    </af:document>
    <af:commandButton text="click me" id="btn">
        <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="popupDialog" />
    </af:commandButton>
</f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like the following:

```
<af:showPopupBehavior popupid="popupDialog" triggerType="action" />
```

That will do the trick

Comment: Did you try what @shay said and added the triggerType at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Your page hierarchy is screwed up.
Try something like:

```
<af:document title="untitled5.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:form id="f1">
        <af:popup id="popupDialog">
            <af:dialog title="Manager" id="dialog1" type="yesNoCancel">
                <af:panelGroupLayout layout="horizontal">
                    <af:outputText value="This is a test"/>
                </af:panelGroupLayout>
            </af:dialog>
        </af:popup>
        <af:commandButton text="click me" id="btn">
            <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="popupDialog"/>
        </af:commandButton>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to put partialSubmit="true"  on af:commandButton

```
<af:commandButton text="click me" id="btn" partialSubmit="true">
        <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="popupDialog" />
    </af:commandButton>
```